# Visual studio does not recognize aspnet_wp.exe when attaching to process

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

This used to work for me, though I just recently formatted my computer and installed windows 7. Now I when I open the attach dialog I cannot even see the aspnet_wp.exe process.

I've configured IIS, and I am accessing it through my global ip address. The website runs fine, but I cannot attach and debug the process.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is w3wp.exe

Comment: Ok that explains. Incredibly fast, thank you both! Have a wonderful weekend

Answer (score 3):

Its called w3wp.exe in IIS7, also remmber to to check the 'Show processes in all sessions'